# structure_sync not working

Tags: 8, configuration

I am trying to use [structure_sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/structure_sync) within my Drupal 8.4.4 project to export the block content of custom blocks as a configuration (see also the discussion "[Custom blocks cannot be properly exported and imported](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2756331)").

Installation via composer went fine and the module also reports everything goes fine when trying the `export-blocks` function for example:

```
$ drush export-blocks
Exporting blocks...
Exported "Copyright"                                          [ok]
Exported "Social Links"                                       [ok]
Exported "Flyout"                                             [ok]
Successfully exported blocks                                  [ok]
The custom blocks have been successfully exported.            [status]
```

However, no configuration files were actually created in the `sync_dir` (or elsewhere).

Is there some other undocumented pre-requisite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom block content needs to be edited and saved again - otherwise `structure_sync` will not be able to recognize, that something has changed and thus it does not want to export the block content.

Answer (score 2):

It is not well explained in the documentation, but `structure_sync` works by generating a new configuration item with all the exported content. It does not generate new files by itself.

Later, when you export the configuration, the new config item appears.